# Uniform Continuity on Compact Set with twist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, compactness, uniform-continuity

I have been asked to prove the following:

Have $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $K = [a,b] \setminus \cup^\infty_{n=1} (\alpha_n,\beta_n)$. Then, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ independent from $x,y$,

$$x \in K, y \in [a,b] : |x-y|< \delta \implies |g(x) - g(y)| < \epsilon$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,\forall x\in K,\forall y\in[a,b]\colon |x-y|<\delta\to |g(x)-g(y)<\epsilon$? This follows form compactness of $K$ (though les trivial than I first thought)

Comment: Yes! sorry if that was unclear!